# Where do I fill and Store an array

Tags: ios, arrays, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

My question is simple : **Using the MVC Pattern**, **where should I save some array** ?

- User --> My `NSObject` class (Model)
- Contact --> My Contact `TableViewController` class, with an Array of `User` (Controller)
- View --> My `Storyboard` (View)

Well, I have a main screen with lots of buttons:

- 1 --> One of those is "Contact".
- 2 --> When I click on it, `mainView` switch to `ContactViewController` (With storyboard push).
- 3 --> This `ContactView` should display my Array of User.

**Considering I use MVC, where should I save / init my Array ?**

- In a new class (Model) called something like "UserList", in the ContactViewController, or somewhere else ?

And even I create a new Model "UserList" for that, where should I call it, so it can load the data when my view Load ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model. Think of the model as the interface to the data stored as plists, sql db etc. of course if your data is not changeable then the model might actually contain/create the data itself. So typically the model would create an array (or an array of arrays) populated from your data in the database or plists. A ViewController would then request one or more of the array entries from the model.

The button "contact" is part of the mainView. It's display is controlled by mainViewController which pushes a new ContactViewController controller on the stack. The ContactViewController should create or retrieve it's data to/from the model, this data will be used to display it's view elements.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that answer. SO my question is "Where" (in what function) should i call my model with the datas.
Because if i do it in the "ViewDidLoad" it's too late, the view already load. 
I can't do it in the "Init" function because it's not call.

So, in what function -inside the ContactViewController- should i do this ? (Initiate my tab).

Comment: If it was me I'd write a custom init method for the viewController: -(id) initWithContactID:(NSString *)theContactID;  In that method I would create my pointer to the shared/singleton Model class and then retrieve the data from the model in that method in the viewController. The data you retrieve from the model could be an array of all the data for that Contact (which you then assign as necessary) or you could get the pieces of data separately (my usual preference).

Comment: Actually you could do it in viewDidLoad, as nothing has been displayed on screen at that point. viewDidLoad is called before viewWillAppear, never mind viewDidAppear. You could do it in init if you call it: [ContactViewController init];

Comment: Btw, as you're using storyboards then you could use prepareForSegue:sender: to tell the view controller which contact to load.

Comment: My apps need to do the same as a website: Show profiles, private messages, events, ...
So i created some class like : profile, event, message, ...
So when someone logon the apps, i retrieve some data (his profile, some events, somme profiles, some messages, ...). 
Is the "best" / "beautiful" way to do this create some new class like : profileS, eventS, messageS. Which are just array of profile, event, message ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new field in your "User" class(User --> My NSObject class (Model)) for that array. If it takes a lot of time to initialize it, then you should initialize it in ViewDidLoad of your ContactViewController.